# How to have several paragraphs in a list item?

Tags: microsoft-word-2011

In a numbered or bulleted list, how would I allow a single list item to include several paragraphs?

For example, when I paste text with line breaks into a list, I get

> - Paragraph 1
> - 
> - Paragraph 2
> - 
> - Paragraph 3

How can I maintain the list indent while grouping under one bullet point?

> - Paragraph 1
>
>   Paragraph 2
>
>   Paragraph 3

Comment: Can you elaborate? To improve your chances of receiving a useful and accurate answer, you should make sure your question has the following: a clear title; a reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can; any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem; correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability. You can find further information on [ask] in the [help].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use styles, rather than just typing “`1.` ” or “`*` ”
or using the buttons in the “Paragraph” group on the “Home” tab. 
Then use the “List Continue” style for paragraphs that are part of a list item,
but not the first paragraph of one. 
For deeper nesting levels, use “List Number *n*”, “List Bullet *n*”, and “List Continue *n*”,
where *n* is an integer starting at 2.
For example,

[image]
<sup>(Image copied from [MS Word: Is there a shortcut for moving between items in numbered or bulleted lists?](https://superuser.com/q/790968/354511))</sup>

Comment: Never mind, I finally located "List Bullet" and "List Continue" in the Styles menu dialog. [The only "List" entry in the Word for Mac 2011 Format > Styles menu that I find merely produces a paragraph whose left margin is indented; but no bullet or numbering choices there. (There is, though, a "List Paragraph" there.) Are you perhaps referring to the Windows version of Word?]

Comment: The “use styles” instruction needs to be expanded. Use styles how?

Comment: You can also use "List Paragraph" style which has the advantage of being in the default style list.

Answer (score 6):

If you want line spacing, with the same indent, use <kbd>Shift + Enter</kbd> for a line-break without incrementing the list; hit just  <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the next list item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution isn't fully correct; It just happens to look like it works with left-aligned text, making it a good quick-and-dirty solution for many documents. It does however break down, if correct spacing of paragraphs is required, or when the text has "justified" alignment. Instead, for me pressing `Enter` and then deleting the number with `Backspace` gives the desired result. (Word 2016.)

Comment: @kdb I've been doing the same as you, but I have a lagging problem when my document gets long enough. Word (for Mac) lags when I click the bullet button to resume list creation. This goes for bulleted lists and numbered lists, except I can fix it with numbered lists and say "Restart numbering" which clears up the problem. BUT, I can't do that with bulleted lists since they are not numbered. Have you run into anything like this?

Comment: @DavidMordigal Not in this particular case. But I *do* know that Office has sometimes issues keeping up with real-time rendering of the document. If you've ever tried using the Outline view in a large Powerpoint document with equations... It is painful.